# typescript currying with default parameters

Tags: typescript, currying

Why can't we have default parameters in curried function in Typescript.

Consider the following example:

```
function add(a: number): (b: number, c:number = 0) => number {
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return function(b: number, c: number = 0): number {
        return a + b + c;
    }
} 

add(10)(5); //I want to call like this
```

The underlined is the error part.

> A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor
>   implementation.

This is what linter saying. If this is the case, is there any way to have default parameters on curried function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that when you declare the function `add`, `(b: number, c:number = 0) => number` is the return type - you're telling the compiler what sort of functions are acceptable as a return value. Default values aren't part of the type though, they're part of the implementation.

Having a parameter be optional is part of the type, however, so this is valid:

```
function add(a: number): (b: number, c?: number) => number {
    return function(b: number, c: number = 0): number {
        return a + b + c;
    };
}
```